# Coordinates of IN_FID and NEAR_FID

Tags: arcmap, proximity

When we run Generate Near Table tool in ArcMap 10.4.1, we get IN_FID and NEAR_FID.
I ran it through my point features and have my data.
But, I also want coordinates of IN_FID points and NEAR_FID points in the same table.
Suggest a clue. I use ArcGIS 10.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Location parameter of [Generate Near Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm) and you will get:

> FROM_X     X-coordinate of the location on the input feature which is
>   closest to the near feature.
>
> FROM_Y     Y-coordinate of the location on the input feature which is
>   closest to the near feature.
>
> NEAR_X     X-coordinate of the location on the near feature which is
>   closest to the input feature.
>
> NEAR_Y     Y-coordinate of the location on the near feature which is
>   closest to the
>
> input feature.